# Stuck at this JAVA Multi-dimensional array problem for some time now, please help me out

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

At the start, the program should read two positive integer numbers that represent the number of rows and seats in each row. Then, it should print a menu with the following three items:

- ***Show the seats*** should print the current seating arrangement. The empty seats should be marked with an S symbol, and taken seats are marked with a B symbol.
- ***Buy a ticket*** should read the seat coordinates from the input and print the ticket price like in the previous stage. After that, the chosen seat should be marked with a B when the item Show the seats is called.
- ***Exit*** should stop the program.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

  static int rowNum;
  static int seatNum;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of rows:");
    int rows = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the number of seats in each row:");
    int seats = scanner.nextInt();


    boolean flag = true;
    while (flag != false) {
      System.out.println("1. Show the seats");
      System.out.println("2. Buy a ticket");
      System.out.println("0. Exit");

      int option = scanner.nextInt();

      switch (option) {
      case 1:
        showSeats(rows, seats, rowNum, seatNum);
        break;

      case 2:
        buyTicket(rows, seats);
        break;

      case 0:
        flag = false;
        break;
      }
    }

  }


private static void showSeats(int rows, int seats, int rowNum, int seatNum) {
    char[][] cinemaHall = new char[rows+1][seats+1];
    System.out.println("Cinema:");
    char count = '1';

    for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= seats; j++) {
            cinemaHall[i][j] = 'S';
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= seats; j++) {
            cinemaHall[0][0] = ' ';
            cinemaHall[0][j] = count;
            count++;
        }
        count = '1';
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
            cinemaHall[i][j] = count;
            count++;

        }
    }

    if (cinemaHall[rowNum][seatNum] == 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= seats; j++) {
            System.out.print(cinemaHall[i][j] + " ");
        } System.out.println();
    }
    } else {
      char b = 'B';
      cinemaHall[rowNum][seatNum] = b;
      for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j <= seats; j++) {
            System.out.print(cinemaHall[i][j] + " ");
          } System.out.println();
      }
    }
  }

private static void buyTicket(int rows, int seats) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a row number:");
    int rowNum1 = scanner.nextInt();
    rowNum = rowNum1;
    System.out.println("Enter a seat number in that row:");
    int seatNum1 = scanner.nextInt();
    seatNum = seatNum1;

    int first = rows / 2;
    int ticketPrice = 0;

    if (rows * seats < 60) {
        ticketPrice = 10;
    } else if (rowNum <= first) {
        ticketPrice = 10;
    } else {
        ticketPrice = 8;
    }
    System.out.println("Ticket price: $" + ticketPrice);
    System.out.println();

  }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
Enter the number of rows:
> 7
Enter the number of seats in each row:
> 7

1. Show the seats
2. Buy a ticket
0. Exit
> 1

Cinema:
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 S S S S S S S
2 S S S S S S S
3 S S S S S S S
4 S S S S S S S
5 S S S S S S S
6 S S S S S S S
7 S S S S S S S

1. Show the seats
2. Buy a ticket
0. Exit
> 2

Enter a row number:
> 4
Enter a seat number in that row:
> 5
Ticket price: $10

1. Show the seats
2. Buy a ticket
0. Exit
> 1

Cinema:
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 S S S S S S S
2 S S S S S S S
3 S S S S S S S
4 S S S S B S S
5 S S S S S S S
6 S S S S S S S
7 S S S S S S S

1. Show the seats
2. Buy a ticket
0. Exit
> 2

Enter a row number:
> 6
Enter a seat number in that row:
> 6
Ticket price: $10

1. Show the seats
2. Buy a ticket
0. Exit
> 1

Cinema:
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 S S S S S S S
2 S S S S S S S
3 S S S S S S S
4 S S S S B S S
5 S S S S S S S
6 S S S S S B S
7 S S S S S S S

1. Show the seats
2. Buy a ticket
0. Exit
> 0
```

Problem with my output:
(1) when ***Show the seats*** runs for the first time, at **cinemaHall [0][0]** it prints  ***B*** even though I've tried to handle it through the if-else block.
(2)The array is resetting after every call to the  ***Buy a ticket*** method, so when I buy another seat the program doesn't show the already booked seat.

Comment: You are only storing the 2d array inside of `showSeats`, how do you expect `buyTicket` to interact with the array in any way?  You should have an array you initialize elsewhere and pass it to the methods that require it.

Comment: Just a suggestion, when solving these problems at first you might think you need a 2D array but in this case you dont. You can have a 1D array and still solve the problem. Allocating mem and assigning elements to array is expensive. Modern languages (like Rust) advice against 2D arrays. (Unless of course you have a strong case for having them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do few changes in the code,

1. the 2d character array need to be used as in static context because you are using the same array for the changes.
2. `showSeats` method needs to check if there is a value already set for the particular seat and if not change the seats.

so after those changes code will look like this,

```
static int rowNum;
static int seatNum;
static char[][] cinemaHall;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of rows:");
    int rows = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the number of seats in each row:");
    int seats = scanner.nextInt();
    cinemaHall = new char[rows+1][seats+1];

    boolean flag = true;
    while (flag != false) {
        System.out.println("1. Show the seats");
        System.out.println("2. Buy a ticket");
        System.out.println("0. Exit");

        int option = scanner.nextInt();

        switch (option) {
            case 1:
                showSeats(rows, seats, rowNum, seatNum);
                break;

            case 2:
                buyTicket(rows, seats);
                break;

            case 0:
                flag = false;
                break;
        }
    }

}


private static void showSeats(int rows, int seats, int rowNum, int seatNum) {
    System.out.println("Cinema:");
    char count = '1';

    for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= seats; j++) {
            if(cinemaHall[i][j]!='B'){
                cinemaHall[i][j] = 'S';
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= seats; j++) {
            cinemaHall[0][j] = count;
            count++;
        }
        count = '1';
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
            cinemaHall[i][j] = count;
            count++;

        }
    }

    
    char b = 'B';
    cinemaHall[rowNum][seatNum] = b;
    cinemaHall[0][0] = ' ';
    for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= seats; j++) {
            System.out.print(cinemaHall[i][j] + " ");
            } System.out.println();
        }          
    }

private static void buyTicket(int rows, int seats) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a row number:");
    int rowNum1 = scanner.nextInt();
    rowNum = rowNum1;
    System.out.println("Enter a seat number in that row:");
    int seatNum1 = scanner.nextInt();
    seatNum = seatNum1;

    int first = rows / 2;
    int ticketPrice = 0;

    if (rows * seats < 60) {
        ticketPrice = 10;
    } else if (rowNum <= first) {
        ticketPrice = 10;
    } else {
        ticketPrice = 8;
    }
    System.out.println("Ticket price: $" + ticketPrice);
    System.out.println();

}
```

and sample output is displayed below,

```
Enter the number of rows:
5
Enter the number of seats in each row:
5
1. Show the seats
2. Buy a ticket
0. Exit
1
Cinema:
  1 2 3 4 5 
1 S S S S S 
2 S S S S S 
3 S S S S S 
4 S S S S S 
5 S S S S S 
1. Show the seats
2. Buy a ticket
0. Exit
2
Enter a row number:
1
Enter a seat number in that row:
1
Ticket price: $10

1. Show the seats
2. Buy a ticket
0. Exit
1
Cinema:
  1 2 3 4 5 
1 B S S S S 
2 S S S S S 
3 S S S S S 
4 S S S S S 
5 S S S S S 
1. Show the seats
2. Buy a ticket
0. Exit
2
Enter a row number:
2
Enter a seat number in that row:
1
Ticket price: $10

1. Show the seats
2. Buy a ticket
0. Exit
1
Cinema:
  1 2 3 4 5 
1 B S S S S 
2 B S S S S 
3 S S S S S 
4 S S S S S 
5 S S S S S 
1. Show the seats
2. Buy a ticket
0. Exit
0
```

Comment: the first part of the original problem is still there, while running **show seats** method for the first time, the program still shows 'B' at (0,0).

Comment: Update the last `else` in `showSeats()` with `else if(cinemaHall[rowNum][seatNum] > 0)`